# Replacing part of a tileset with gdal2tiles

Tags: tiles, gdal2tiles

Is it possible to run gdal2tiles to replace a specific part of a tileset?

We've created a tileset whose generation took almost 2 days and then found out that one of the input files had an issue (it shows up white). It would be awesome to just replace that one input file and have it tiled so it fits into the final tileset.

I am almost positive I read that gdal2tiles can do that, but I really cannot find anything about it anymore. Was I reading about a different software, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you are/were looking for.

`-e, --resume`
Resume mode. Generate only missing files.

More information: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html